# Making the abstract's font looks better

Tags: fonts, abstract

How do I to make this `Abstract`'s font written in Frensh looks better?

Any brilliant idea, please ?

[image]

For example, this font-style that I can't find how to make it:
[image]

Its related code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Résumé}
Ce stage résume notre expérience de deux mois dans l'été de 2012..
Au cours de cette période, nous avons intégré \`{a} distance une équipe
sur le projet « Barboteau ». Notre rôle a été de concevoir et développer
un site web d'un groupe de musique. Nous avons utilisé le langage
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking a way to use Times New Roman as a font for your document?

Comment: @karlkoeller, I'm just trying to make this nice looking, not a standard or a simple text.

Comment: Have a look at [The LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). probably you'll find one that meets your needs.

Comment: Note that you should use the `abstract` *environment* rather than making it a chapter. See Bernard's answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Lobster2 font. It works either with (pdf)LaTeX or with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, as it exists in type 1 and OpenType formats. Here is a version with pdflatex:

```
        \documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage{abstract}
        \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\usefont{T1}{LobsterTwo-LF}{bx}{it}\LARGE}
        \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalsize}
        \setlength{\abstitleskip}{4\baselineskip}

        \usepackage{babel}
        \begin{document}

        \begin{abstract}
         Ce stage résume notre expérience de deux mois dans l'été de 2012..Au cours de cette période, nous avons intégré à distance une équipe
        sur le projet « Barboteau ». Notre rôle a été de concevoir et développer un site web d'un groupe de musique. Nous avons utilisé le langage
        \end{abstract}

        \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With xelatex, you can choose any system font, use OpenType features and do some letterspacing. Then replace the above preamble with:

```
        \documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
        \usepackage{fontspec}

        \usepackage{abstract}
        \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\fontspec[LetterSpace=1.0]{LobsterTwo-BoldItalic}\LARGE}
        \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalsize}
        \setlength{\abstitleskip}{4\baselineskip}

        \usepackage{babel}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, can I use this font to other purposes? how do I that, please ?

Comment: This wouldn't work, [look](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vtH57.png)

Comment: @user3289501: It seems like (pdf|xe)latex doesn't find the  (type1|otf) font. How was it installed on your system? With the package manager or manually? Did you run `initexmf --mkmaps`? Check if the font is mentioned in `psfonts.map`. If not, run initexmf --mkmaps and check again. If it doesn't work and you're under windows, you can install the opentype font on your system, and run xelatex, which will find it – and you'll be able to use it in other applications.

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen your comment. I'm under Windows. To add a Package, I need to use `Package Manager` and to search using keywords. Typing `xelatex` doesn't return any result.

Comment: Do you use MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: I'm using MiKteX

Comment: OK. If you installed Lobster2 with the Package Manager, the`updmap.cfg` in \MiKTeX 2.9 contains this line: `Map LobsterTwo.map`. So all you have to do is to run from the command prompt(possibly as administrator – or both): `updmap --verbose`. The switch will you see what really happens.Normally, LaTeX will then know where to find the Lobster2 font and you should be able to compile with it.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find it. I've found your font in [this site](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lobster-two) will need to simply download it? and add it into the folder in which is placed my LaTeX file ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13058/discussion-between-bernard-and-user3289501)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few more examples using the `abstract` package from Bernard's answer. More calligraphic fonts are listed in the font catalogue mentioned in the comments on the original question. Some of those included in TeX Live and some are only available from CTAN.

The fonts in my sample are all part of TeX Live and are all available in type1 format.

[image: Calligraphic, handwriting and cursive fonts]

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{pbsi}% for Brush Script
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{aurical}% for Lukas Svatba
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tgcstyle}{% for Tex Gyre Chorus
        \fontencoding{T1}%
        \fontseries{m}%
        \fontshape{it}%
        \fontfamily{qzc}%
        \selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\zapfstyle}{% for Zapf Chancery
        \fontencoding{T1}%
        \fontseries{mb}%
        \fontshape{it}%
        \fontfamily{pzc}%
        \selectfont}

% use Bernard's strategy for the abstract
\usepackage{abstract}

% make it easy to typeset a number of examples for comparison
\newcommand{\exabstract}[2][\normalfont]{%
  \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{#2}%
  \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{#1}%
  \begin{abstract}
   Ce stage résume notre expérience de deux mois dans l'été de 2012..Au cours de cette période, nous avons intégré à distance une équipe
  sur le projet « Barboteau ». Notre rôle a été de concevoir et développer un site web d'un groupe de musique. Nous avons utilisé le langage
  \end{abstract}
}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\exabstract{\Fontlukas\Huge}
\exabstract{\Fontamici\Huge}% same font with long s and extra ligatures
\exabstract{\bsifamily\LARGE}
\exabstract{\calligra\LARGE}\clearpage
\exabstract{\cursive\LARGE\bfseries}
\exabstract{\tgcstyle\Huge}% based on Zapf Chancery but extended
\exabstract{\zapfstyle\Huge}

\end{document}
```